# Problem with the POSIX module

Tags: perl, posix, freebsd, mod-perl

After moving my mod_perl site from Linux hosting to FreeBSD, I have this error in the logfile:

> > Your vendor has not defined POSIX macro SIGRTMIN, used at ../../lib/POSIX.pm (autosplit into ../../lib/auto/POSIX/SigRt/_init.al) line 993\n

The script just imports POSIX and utilizes some functions (ceil, etc)

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [importing](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) only few (or none) routines from the module:

```
use POSIX ();
my $n = POSIX::ceil(1.1);
```

This used to work for me in the same circumstances, I don't know why :)

Answer (score 5):

FreeBSD is *mostly* [POSIX-compliant](http://people.freebsd.org/~schweikh/posix-utilities.html). For example, it [doesn't define](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-standards/2006-June/001198.html) `SIGRTMIN` and `SIGRTMAX` in its `signal.h`. We are warned against this in [POSIX's documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#CAVEATS):

> Furthermore, some evil vendors will
>   claim 1003.1 compliance, but in fact
>   are not so: they will not pass the
>   PCTS (POSIX Compliance Test Suites).
>   For example, one vendor may not define
>   EDEADLK, or the semantics of the errno
>   values set by open(2) might not be
>   quite right. Perl does not attempt to
>   verify POSIX compliance. That means
>   you can currently successfully say
>   "use POSIX", and then later in your
>   program you find that your vendor has
>   been lax and there's no usable ICANON
>   macro after all. This could be
>   construed to be a bug.

[eugene y](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244297/eugene-y)'s solution might work as it will prevent auto exporting into your namespace, but be sure to prefix any calls to `ceil` and so on with `POSIX::`.